# How do I see how a suggested edit changes a post before the suggested edit is approved?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Is it possible to see how the suggested edit changes a post, before the suggested edit is approved?

I know there are two views in the suggested edit page.

1. Post before edit
2. Changes done by the suggested user

But there is no option to see how the post will look, once the suggested edit is approved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see already how the edited post would appear if the suggested edit gets approved: Select *rendered output*, and you will see the rendered output before the edit (on the left) and the rendered output after the edit.

> [image: screenshot]

The only difference is the presence of the text with a green background, which is the way used to highlight the text that has been added from the suggested edit. For the rest, the text is exactly formatted as it would appear once the edit is approved.